# Extraer texto de una cadena en python

Tags: python, regex

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de python.

Una de las columnas de mi dataframe tiene los siguientes valores:

```
df_house_sample.house_type_id.values

array(['HouseType 1: Pisos', 'HouseType 1: Pisos', 'HouseType 1: Pisos',
   ..., 'HouseType 1: Pisos', 'HouseType 2: Casa o chalet',
   'HouseType 1: Pisos'], dtype=object)
```

Necesito recuperar todos los tipos de vivienda que quedan después de los dos puntos. Como por ejemplo "Pisos".

He utilizado un bucle y regex, pero no consigo recuperar el tipo de vivienda.

Gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Comment: Ingresa el código que has intentado para basarnos sobre ese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la estructura es esa puedes hacer un split y obtener el segundo elemento que siempre estará después de los dos puntos.

```
listaEjemplo =  ['HouseType 1: Pisos', 'HouseType 1: Pisos', 'HouseType 1: Pisos',
   ..., 'HouseType 1: Pisos', 'HouseType 2: Casa o chalet',
   'HouseType 1: Pisos']
nuevaLista = []
for x in listaEjemplo:
  valor = x.split(":")
  nuevaLista.append(valor[1])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan. Un saludo.